# How to view the contents of google cloud platform snapshot?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

I have a gcp snapshot and I want to read the data(not restoring) of that snapshot. How can I do that? What are the APIs available in gcp for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's reasonable to want to browse (Persistent Disk) Snapshots but you cannot.

You must restore a (series of) Snapshots to a PD in order to browse the content.

Although more involved, you could create a PD, restore the Snapshot, do what you need and then delete the PD without incurring considerable cost.

I assume your use-case is that you'd like to confirm a specific (set of) file(s) has been Snapshotted?

If so, you may wish to consider a formal backup solution. This would provide you with a rich, queryable source of backed up files, would permit you to move backed-up replicas to different locations|media, and could possibly provide online backups whereby you needn't stop applications atop your PDs while backups are taken.